# How to access form input variable values with multiple inputs using a loop in php?

Tags: php

Let's say I have a `"fieldname"` that has multiple form inputs in an HTML form.  In the form, `name="fieldname[]"`.

I then set a `fieldname` variable:

```
 $fieldname = $_POST['fieldname'];
```

I would then use a loop to access each value:

```
 foreach ( $_POST['fieldname'] as a_name ) {
     echo $a_name;
 }
```

I want to use each value in `"fieldname"` in my below `$email_body` variable and then in a mail function.

I have an email_body variable which is used in my mail function:
     `$email_body = "Auto Quote\n From: $email \n $address, $carrier"`

Would I just include the email_body in the squiggly brackets of the foreach loop?  And then put the `$a_name` variable in the quotes?  Or would it be better to use it in my(not shown) mail function?

Comment: Post your array_structure

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  I just have 3 form inputs with name="fieldname[]",  I then access the post array and save into variable $fieldname = $_POST['fieldname'].  Now I am trying to figure out how to use it in my mail function

Comment: @user5198569 A bit difficult to understand your question. Are you looking to send mail to multiple users that are in 'fieldname' input field, or it is a value that need to be send to a single user?

Comment: I just want to use the fieldname values in my $email_body variable (the main contents of the email).  So value that needs to be sent a single user.

Comment: your foreach is wrong. `foreach ($_POST[fieldname] as $a_name)` you are missing `$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're not sure how to use the `$a_name` variables in your message body. How to do this of course depends on where in the message body you want to place the form input, but the following could work:

```
$fieldname = $_POST['fieldname'];
$email_body = "Auto Quote\n From: $email \n $address, $carrier \n"

foreach ($_POST['fieldname'] as $a_name ) {
    $email_body .= $a_name . "\n";
}
```

This will append the input in the "fieldname" forms to your message body. If you want to place the input in a different place, you should clearly just switch things around. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You did almost everything. `$_POST['fieldname']` is an array, so after `$fieldname = $_POST['fieldname'];`, a copy of the array is in `$fieldname`, no need to use `$_POST['fieldname']` anymore.

To add each content to your mail body:

```
$body = 'Whatever text before: ';

foreach ($fieldname as $index => $value ) {
  $body .= $index . ': ' . $value . ';';
}

$body .= 'text after.';

//send your e-mail
```

You can use `$_POST['fieldname']` directly without `$fieldname` variable.

I put an index that you can ignore if you want, see PHP `foreach` documentation if needed http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php.

As the text from client is being used, You must be aware of the fact that a dot by itself on a line ends the e-mail body, I don`t know how PHP mail functions handle this, may be some testing is appropriate.